Visual Studio Debug is very slow with Razor Runtime Compilation ON in my system ONLY
I have VS 17.10 and am using this extension in my asp.net core (.net 6) to turn runtime razor compilation ON:
RazorRuntimeCompilationMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddServices(builder.Services);
This however is tremendously slowing down my application from loading, while and only while debugging. My machine takes ~46s to load this one particular razor page, while a couple of colleague's takes only ~8s. My CPU and Memory usage aren't terrible. We all have similar systems. I have also reset my VS settings to avail.
There are a whole lot of Razor pages (child pages) involved and I get these loading messages for some ~50 assemblies (corresponding to different child pages):
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'y3bjdb4m.e2v'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded '1kxxxkso.iuc'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'asqc3qse.c1z'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 't4bl1glf.nuh'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'bxbooev3.eeq'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'ygghqrqy.jkp'. 
...exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'bnffzdaf.eyb'. 

... which seem to slow down the page load.
Any ideas what setting in my system could be slowing this down?
